# integration of jquery inside webform using master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I've an application MVC 4 where unfortunately i need to put few aspx web forms in order to use ReportViewerControl ...

My problem is that 
trying to use a MasterPage for these aspx web forms, jquery stopped working.

This is masterPage code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterAspx.master.cs" Inherits="GestioneMovimentazioni.MasterAspx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/red_green_white/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <div id="div_header" class="div_header">
            <div class="float-left">
                <img src="~/Images/img_sx_r.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="page_title" class="float-left div_header_page_title" >

            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <img src="~/Images/img_dx_r.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the form

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterAspx.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BilCom.aspx.cs" Inherits="GestioneMovimentazioni.BilCom" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#txtDate').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .ui-datepicker-calendar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


      <div class="div_display_table">
            <div class="div_display_table_row">
                <div class="div_display_table_cell">
                    <label id="label_data_filter">Mese</label>
                </div>

               <div class="div_display_table_cell">
                    <label id="label1">Calcola</label>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="div_display_table_row">
                <div class="div_display_table_cell">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" class="input_add w_80"></asp:TextBox>

                </div>
                                  <div class="div_display_table_cell">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCalcola" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calcola.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>

               <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />

            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="900px" Height="650px"
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Calibri"
                WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">

            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
         </div>

</asp:Content>
```

can you help me to understand why datepicker has stopped working?
thank you!

Comment: Q1- jQuery stopped working or date picker stopped working and jQuery loads successfully? Q2- Why do you have `.ui-datepicker-calendar {display:none;}` ?

Comment: What does "stopped working" means?

Comment: Thank you, Q1 - jquery stopped working and Q2 - to display only month and week without days –

Comment: I've found the problem! 
By putting DOM elements inside ContentPlaceHolder their DOM name changed. 
So $('#txtDate').datepicker works if the selector is corrected in this way $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDate').datepicker();

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the property "**ClientIDMode**" of the asp textbox to "**Static**"